# Zend Framework Data Mapper problem

Tags: zend-framework

It has been a rough task to learn this framework. I am still stuck at quick start.

I am using `PDO_MYSQL` as my adapter. I have followed the tutorial to the letters.

At a point, it says to create `application/models/GuestbookMapper.php` and put the following code

```
class Application_Model_GuestbookMapper
{
    public function save($model);
    public function find($id, $model);
    public function fetchAll();
}
```

Then it say to run this command

```
zf create model GuestbookMapper
```

The tutorials claims to **insert additional methods**. But in my case, it emptied the my GuestbookMapper class with this

```
class Application_Model_GuestbookMapper
{

}
```

Same goes with another command `zf create model Guestbook`. It empties the scripts, with just plain class defination.

Please help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-read the QuickStart carefully. You're probably skimming and getting hung up.

Here is the text:

> **A typical API for a data mapper is as follows:**
>
> ```
> class Application_Model_GuestbookMapper
> {
>     public function save($model);
>     public function find($id, $model);
>     public function fetchAll();
> }
> ```

And then...

> In addition to these methods, we'll add methods for setting and retrieving the Table Data Gateway. **To create the initial class**, use the zf CLI tool:
>
> `% zf create model GuestbookMapper`

Lastly...

> Now, edit the class Application_Model_GuestbookMapper found in application/models/GuestbookMapper.php to read as follows:

Note that the first example is just that - *an example*. They are providing a sample interface of what your class will probably look like. The second block of text explains how to create your initial (empty) class. And the last block gives you the exact final code of the `GuestbookMapper` class.

Answer (score -1):

Just add those methods again ;) Won't that work?